# Missing first character when output string

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks

When I try to input name to array, its output that missing the first character like that: `john` to `ohn`. I used `cin.ignore();` and `cin.getline(name,30);`. But when I delete `cin.ignore();`, it creates an issue during input. So what is the problem? I used `code::block` IDE.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class love {
    private:
    char name[30];
    public:
    void input_name();
    void output_name();
};

void love::input_name() {

    cout<<"Input Name :";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,30);
}

void love::output_name() {
    cout<<name<<endl;
}

int main() {
    love obj[10];
    int n;
    int i,j,k;

    for (k=1;k>n;k++) {
    }

    cout<<"Input n student name : ";cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        obj[i].input_name();
    }

    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        obj[j].output_name();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you have a loop which does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

If you call ignore without any parameters, it will ignore the first character.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

```
istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);
```

In your case, I would avoid using getline and ignore.
Change it to a simple:

```
cin >> name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constructor in your "love" class.
You cannot construct love normally, without it.

Comment: The compiler will create default/copy/move constructor(s) if they are used. You could specify them yourself, if you need extra initialization or have to do something inside of it.